# weatheR data package

Tags: r, api

using weatheR package i need data from a specific station, so i tried to use getStationByID funciont.
The station is GROTTAGLIE and in my station.list df its USAF id is 163240:

```
require(devtools)
install_github("mpiccirilli/weatheR")
require(weatheR)
station.list <- allStations()

station.list %>% filter(USAF==163240)


USAF     WBAN       NAME   CTRY   STATE    ICAO    LAT    LON      ELEV    BEGIN      END 
 163240   99999  GROTTAGLIE  IT           LIBG    40.518    17.403    65.5    19430927 20170710
```

if i launch the funcion

```
grottaglie<- getStationByID(stationID = '163240',station.list = station.list, begin = 2013, 2016)
```

i get

> Error in names(combined.list)[i] <- keys[i] :
>       'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `weatheR` package seems to be an abandoned project.
Looking inside the code of the `getStationByID` function, one can realize that it cannot work.
A modified `getStationByID` is available [here](https://pastebin.com/Gbthurxf).
 
Download this file and save it in the working directory with the name `mygetStationByID.r`.
Then, use the following code:

```
require(weatheR)
station.list <- allStations()

# Load the modified version of getStationByID   
source("mygetStationByID.r")
# The structure of the fixed-width files 
# downloaded from ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/
col.width <- c(4,6,5,8,4,1,6,7,5,5,5,4)
# Column names
col.names <- c("TOT", "USAF", "WBAN", "DATE", "TIME", "DATASOURCE",
 "LAT","LON","CODE","ELEV.DIM","CALL.LETTER","QLT.CTRL")

grottaglie <- mygetStationByID(stationID = 163240,
             station.list = station.list, begin = 2013, end=2016)

str(grottaglie)
# List of 2
#  $ dl_status   :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ File  : chr [1:4] "163240-99999-2013.gz" "163240-99999-2014.gz" "163240-99999-2015.gz" "163240-99999-2016.gz"
#   ..$ Status: chr [1:4] "Failed" "Failed" "Failed" "Failed"
#   ..$ City  : chr [1:4] "Grottaglie, Italy" "Grottaglie, Italy" "Grottaglie, Italy" "Grottaglie, Italy"
#   ..$ rank  : num [1:4] 1 1 1 1
#  $ station_data:List of 1
#   ..$ Grottaglie_163240:'data.frame':   19264 obs. of  12 variables:
#   .. ..$ TOT        : int [1:19264] 126 126 138 137 145 145 145 137 89 89 ...
#   .. ..$ USAF       : int [1:19264] 163240 163240 163240 163240 163240 163240 163240 163240 163240 163240 ...
#   .. ..$ WBAN       : int [1:19264] 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999 ...
#   .. ..$ DATE       : int [1:19264] 20130101 20130101 20130101 20130101 20130101 20130101 20130101 20130101 20130101 20130101 ...
#   .. ..$ TIME       : int [1:19264] 650 750 850 950 1050 1250 1350 1450 1550 1650 ...
#   .. ..$ DATASOURCE : int [1:19264] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
#   .. ..$ LAT        : num [1:19264] 40.5 40.5 40.5 40.5 40.5 ...
#   .. ..$ LON        : int [1:19264] 17400 17400 17400 17400 17400 17400 17400 17400 17400 17400 ...
#   .. ..$ CODE       : Factor w/ 2 levels "FM-15","FM-16": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#   .. ..$ ELEV.DIM   : int [1:19264] 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 69 ...
#   .. ..$ CALL.LETTER: Factor w/ 2 levels "99999","LIBG ": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#   .. ..$ QLT.CTRL   : Factor w/ 1 level "V020": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

# Table by years 
table(as.numeric(substr(grottaglie$station_data[[1]]$DATE, 1, 4)))
# 2013 2014 2015 2016 
# 4866 4816 4794 4788
```

I hope it can help you.
N.B. If at the first run the code generates an error message, try to rerun it.

Comment: i just opened an issue on github page. The package creator answered that he wiil work on it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rnoaa`

```
install.packages("rnoaa")
library(rnoaa)
(res <- isd(usaf=163240, wban=99999, year=1986))
#> # A tibble: 7,364 x 78
#>    total_chars usaf_station wban_station     date  time date_flag latitude longitude type_code elevation
#>          <chr>        <chr>        <chr>    <chr> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>
#>  1        0058       163240        99999 19860101  0032         4   +40517   +017400     FM-15     +0069
#>  2        0058       163240        99999 19860101  0100         4   +40517   +017400     FM-15     +0069
#>  3        0058       163240        99999 19860101  0208         4   +40517   +017400     FM-15     +0069
#>  4        0058       163240        99999 19860101  0308         4   +40517   +017400     FM-15     +0069
#>  5        0058       163240        99999 19860101  0408         4   +40517   +017400     FM-15     +0069
#>  6        0074       163240        99999 19860101  0508         4   +40517   +017400     FM-15     +0069
#>  7        0074       163240        99999 19860101  0610         4   +40517   +017400     FM-15     +0069
#>  8        0074       163240        99999 19860101  0710         4   +40517   +017400     FM-15     +0069
#>  9        0074       163240        99999 19860101  0810         4   +40517   +017400     FM-15     +0069
#> 10        0074       163240        99999 19860101  0910         4   +40517   +017400     FM-15     +0069
#> # ... with 7,354 more rows, and 68 more variables: call_letter <chr>, quality <chr>,
#> #   wind_direction <chr>, wind_direction_quality <chr>, wind_code <chr>, wind_speed <chr>,
#> ...
```

Comment: `rnoaa` is actively maintained, and lots of contributors - just fyi

Comment: thank you rnoaa is a great package! I have one question about variables format like elevation or temperature: why i get values like "+0020"? how i can interpret it?

Comment: @andriatz so `rnoaa` is a wrapper for lots of NOAA datasets, so we first focus on just getting data and doing that well. then focus more on fine tuning data formats, etc. later. for ISD data, we are getting better, we have a sep. pakcage https://github.com/ropensci/isdparser to parse ISD data b/c it is so horrible to parse - that might be a good place to raise issues about formatting